# Why is mapping property in hibernate.cfg.xml ignored?

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, hibernate, maven

I'm trying to figure out class mapping via xml in hibernate, following the tutorial from the official site, and I keep getting the same error - org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not found, as a result i cannot get SessionFactory and Session.
I have thoroughly checked all the paths and project structure, tried using both maven and gradle but nothing has helped so far. I'm using postgres DB. Here's my project structure:

[image]

**Here's pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dungeon-hero-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.31.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dungeon</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">nbv67iuy</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>

        <mapping resource="org/dungeonhero/entities/Monster.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Mapping xml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="org.dungeonhero.entities">

    <class name="Monster" table="monsters">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name" column="name"/>
        <property name="maxHealth" column="max_health"/>
        <property name="currentHealth" column="current_health"/>
        <property name="dexterity" column="dexterity"/>
        <property name="dextCoeff" column="dext_coeff"/>
        <property name="currentReadiness" column="current_readiness"/>
        <property name="attack" column="attack"/>


    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Main class:**

```
package entities;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("=================================");
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(new Monster("Goblin", 100, 40, 30));

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Entity class itself (Monster) provides both no-args constructor and getters and setters for each field.

Also, here's stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not found : org/dungeonhero/entities/Monster.hbm.xml : origin(org/dungeonhero/entities/Monster.hbm.xml)
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.bind(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.addResource(MetadataSources.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.spi.MappingReference.apply(MappingReference.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:202)
    at org.dungeonhero.entities.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Maybe I missed something, I will be grateful for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have deleted everything about config, cause project structure was changed.
You should update your `pom.xml` and add build info for your case

```
<build>
    <resources>
       <resource>
          <filtering>false</filtering>
             <directory>src/main/java</directory>
             <includes>
                 <include>**/*.xml</include>
             </includes>
       </resource>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
       </resource>
   </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: And also he has his hbm.xml file in `main/java` instead of `main/resources`, so it doesn't end up in `target/classes`. Even if the package were correct - the file still wouldn't be found.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev i've updated answer

Comment: Sorry, It still won't work, here's what i've made:

1) I changed project structure, now packages hierarchy is correct, it still doesn't work
2) Also in hibernate tutorial project mapping file Entity.hbm.xml is located in the same folder as the entities it is mapping, not in resources. And this tutorial project works just fine.
3) Anyways, i moved mapping xml file to resources, and updated its path in hibernate.cfg.xml with <mapping resource="Monster.hbm.xml"/> , but it still won't work

Comment: I've updated screenshot of file structure in the main question

Comment: @vetal22331122 do you see the same error?

Comment: Yes, I do. Also, I've admitted that my mapping file doesn't exist in target/classes, as Stanislav mentioned above. But I have Hibernate tutorial project opened as example, and I do everything just like in this example project, but tutorial project builds fine, despite the fact, that it has its mapping file not in resources, but in java folder. But ib=n example project mapping file still ends up in target/classes

Comment: @Alex Yes, I do. Also, I've admitted that my mapping file doesn't exist in target/classes, as Stanislav mentioned above. But I have Hibernate tutorial project opened as example, and I do everything just like in this example project, but tutorial project builds fine, despite the fact, that it has its mapping file not in resources, but in java folder. But example project mapping file still ends up in target/classes –

Comment: @vetal22331122 try to update `pom.xml`. I've updated answer

Comment: @vetal22331122 check the answer as correct please if it solves your issue